# Select Two query in one query with multiple column

Tags: mysql, self-join

I am getting the issue I want to select two different queries in one query but different column
Note: Not like union because union put these two queries in one column

```
select count(id) as lead,SUM(ol.publisher_earned) as earning from offer_process as ol 
where ol.status='Approved'  and ol.publisher_id='1738' and ol.created_at>='2021-08-01' GROUP by date(ol.created_at)

select count(ol2.id) as clicks from offer_process as ol2  where   ol2.publisher_id='1738'  and ol2.created_at>='2021-08-01' GROUP by date(ol2.created_at)
```

Comment: For union data type must be same.  IS SUM(ol.publisher_earned) and count(ol2.id) datatype same or different. If different then UNION will not work.

Comment: yes but I don't want to union I want two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this. If created_date isn't need at SELECT clause then discard it.

```
SELECT date(created_at) created_at
     , COUNT(publisher_id) clicks
     , SUM(CASE WHEN status='Approved' THEN publisher_earned ELSE 0 END) earning
FROM offer_process
WHERE publisher_id='1738'
    AND created_at>='2021-08-01'
GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

Comment: wow you make my day please explain count(1)

Comment: COUNT(1) or COUNT(id)  is same. You can use anyone.

Comment: Welcome @HabibUrRehman for accepting my answer. If possible please upvote my answer along with accepted. Negative vote in an accepting answer looks odd.

Comment: I can't vote because my reputation is  13

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT earning,clicks FROM
(
    select ol.publisher_id,SUM(ol.publisher_earned) as earning from offer_process as ol 
    where ol.status='Approved'  and ol.publisher_id='1738' and ol.created_at>='2021-08-01' GROUP by date(ol.created_at),ol.publisher_id
)ol
JOIN
(
    select ol2.publisher_id, count(ol2.id) as clicks from offer_process as ol2  
    where ol2.publisher_id='1738'  and ol2.created_at>='2021-08-01' GROUP by date(ol2.created_at),ol2.publisher_id
)ol2 On ol.publisher_id=ol2.publisher_id
```

Comment: the first query give 27 rows individually and the second return 23 but your query return 621 rows